# Button position from dialog to activity

Tags: java, android, dialog, position, screen

I've been trying to get the position from a button inside a dialog so that i can use it to place a button below that button in the activity.

I've tried a few things but none of them seem to work

```
int loc1[] = new int[2];
button.getLocationInWindow(loc1);

int loc2[] = new int[2];
button.getLocationOnScreen(loc2);
```

I've also tried

```
button.getX();
button.getY();
```

The button was never placed below the button in the dialog.

(I should note that i only mentioned the methods to get the postiion)

Can anybody help me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait for the callback when the Button has placed. The code you are using not returning the proper value because the value is returned before the Button is placed. So add the Button in a layout with height/width as wrap_content and Use this code:

```
layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

    int[] locations = new int[2];
     layout.getLocationOnScreen(locations);
    int x = locations[0];
    int y = locations[1];
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make layout params, they depend on the parent, so you should probably use  `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` or `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` (there are other cases).

And add `layout_below(button1)` to your LayoutParams object. And set that LayoutParams to new button you want to appear below first button1.